# Drupal search like in yelp

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

i want to have search function like in http://www.yelp.com or http://www.eventbrite.com/directory on my site. There are 2 fields, title and city for the search. How can i do this in drupal 7?

Thanks,
Reynaldi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get best user experience check out [Apache solr](http://www.slideshare.net/nickvh/drupal-apachesolr) drupal modules for example [Apache Solr Search Integration](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr). Thou I have to warn you it will be much more complicated to setup and manage than any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use http://drupal.org/project/Custom_Search. But also you can do this with views and exposed filters. Drupal have many ways to do this.